# Clear the list in do-while loop

Tags: java, android, arraylist, do-while

I am using a do-while loop.In that loop I am having a condition check,whenever the condition fails, the list must get cleared. I am trying but I am not getting the expected result.

```
List<Date> myDateList=new ArrayList<Date>();
int zTmp=0;

do  
{
 if(condition true)
  {
    //do task
  }else{
    myDateList.clear();
   //I wish to clear this list when condition fails
  }
  zTmp++;
}while(zTmp<myList.size());
```

Comment: Is myDateList a listview? What is its declaration?

Comment: where is condition become false

Comment: @Sas I have declared myDateList also. Please find the changes

Comment: What is your condition will you put some more code .

Comment: else.... part... I mean when condition is true, it must do task, else it must clear the list

Comment: have you called the notifyDataSetChanged() method on the adapter ??

Comment: List<Date> myDateList=new ArrayList<Date>() ;

Comment: try displaying some Log in the else part to know whether exactly the condition is getting false or not. and Instead of clearing the list, initialize the list again using **myDateList = new ArrayList<E>**

Comment: Did you try debugging it? Does it go in else part when your condition fails?

Answer (score 1):

I wonder how you can call clear() on ListView.Rather you should consider calling clear on Adapter which is set on ListView.

Below snippet will help you.

```
adapter.clear();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I am not dealing with ListView 
List<Date> myDateList=new ArrayList<Date>() ;

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why clear is not working... But work around for this is to assign a new Object to list. So instead using `myDateList.clear()` you can use `myDateList = new ArrayList<T>()` or `myDateList = new LinkedList<T>()`.

Just a doubt: Is your condition failing even once?